# Calling AWS Query API from Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-data-pipeline

I am new to AWS. I have created a Data Pipeline through SDK and I have created a pipeline definition in JSON format and want to update the pipeline definition using the JSON which I have created through SDK. Is there a way to call AWS Query API from AWS SDK so that I can maintain single code snippet to create multiple pipelines.

Also Is it possible to call any AWS Query APIs/Restful services from SDK?

Comment: Can you give us any specific details? What service are you using? What is the pipeline definition file called. I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: The AWS SDK is built on top of the AWS Query API/REST API. The entire point of the AWS SDK is to provide an easy way to call the AWS API. I suggest taking some time to look at the SDK docs.